# Installing php extension for ffmpg is not working in windows10 xampp3.2 php5.6

Tags: php, ffmpeg-php

I have downloaded the php extension for ffmpeg and pasted it in ext folder and added the same in php.ini. Also added the files pthreadGC2.dll,avcodec.dll and avformat.dll on system32. But when I restart apache and look in to the phpinfo, the ffmpeg extension is not visible in that.

Can someone help me to install it?

in error log I get something like,
Unable to load dynamic library php_ffmpeg.dll - The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this steps: it worked for me

-> Copy php_ffmpeg.dll to xampp\php\ext.

-> Copy ffmpeg.exe into root of your site or anywhere else as long you know where (you will have to define path to it in your php file)...

-> Copy everything else to windows/system32.

-> Add "extension=php_ffmpeg.dll" or remove ";" on the beginning of that line in php.ini file (xampp\php\php.ini )

->Restart apache server

:)